# npm5 equivalent to yarn's --pure-lockfile flag?

Tags: npm, package-lock.json

I'm looking for an equivalent for yarn's [`--pure-lockfile` flag](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-pure-lockfile).

This flag is useful when installing dependencies in CI, when you want it to read your lockfile but not modify it.

Does npm v5 have an equivalent?

Comment: Kind of duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/45022048/1480391

Answer (score 27, accepted):

npm 5.7 introduced the `npm ci` subcommand:

> the main differences between using `npm install` and `npm ci` are:
>
> - The project **must** have an existing `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.
> - If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in `package.json`, `npm ci` will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock.
> - `npm ci` can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.
> - If a `node_modules` is already present, it will be automatically removed before `npm ci` begins its install.
> - It will never write to `package.json` or any of the package-locks: installs are essentially frozen.

Comment: Personally i hate the fact that `npm ci` removes the node_modules folder, as this kills off any form of caching for CI-Pipelines and thereby slows pipelines. IMHO it creates a lot of unnecessary load on the npm infrastructure and waiting times on our side, but it's the best we get.

Comment: You can cache the `.npm` cache folder, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60355056/132208

Answer (score -3):

this is how I did in my `dockerfile`

```
RUN npm install --pure-lockfile
```

it should work perfect.

Comment: I've looked and found no documentation for anything called `--pure-lockfile` in npm. I believe this flag is ignored.