# Is there a way of making "npm ci" install devDependencies, or "npm install" not update package-lock.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-ci

I'm trying to put together documentation for new developers installing our codebase on their local development environments.  I'd like to give them command(s) that:

- Installs both devDependencies and dependencies based on the versions in package-lock.json
- Doesn't update package-lock.json

"npm ci" does almost exactly what I want, but doesn't seem to install devDependencies.  "npm install" does install devDependencies, but it sometimes modifies package-lock.json.

I could imagine something janky like "npm install && git checkout package-lock.json", but I feel like there must be a more idiomatic way of saying "give me a clean install of this project's dependencies for development?"

Answer (score 121, accepted):

`npm ci` does install both dependecies and dev dependencies. But if you use `npm ci --production` or if your `NODE_ENV` is set to production, then it avoids installing dev dependencies.
Please check docs [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

> With the `--production` flag (or when the `NODE_ENV` environment
>   variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in
>   devDependencies.
>
> NOTE: The `--production` flag has no particular meaning when adding a
>   dependency to a project.

Comment: So how do you `npm install` then `npm test` and then remove devdependencies? If you `npm install --only=production` then you cannot run tests.

Comment: @Mark `npm install --no-save` or `npm ci`, then `npm test`, then `npm prune --production`

Comment: The doc you are linking to is for `npm install`.  The `npm ci` page does not list **ANY** command line flags.  Does `npm ci` support all the same command line flags as `npm install`?  I would expect this to be clearly called out in the docs somewhere if that is the case.  Otherwise there are a lot of answers about "use this flag" where people may add options to commands that ignore them.  If I run `npm install --foobar`, npm doesn't warn or complain that that is an invalid option.  So good chance lots of people are using CLI options that do nothing.

Comment: For future readers, just to clarify @mattpr's comment, `npm ci --production` does work as intended. (I tested it.) Perhaps one could raise a PR to update the `npm ci` documentation.

Comment: Going foward, use --omit=dev instead of --production

Comment: I have the same problem, npm version 8.19.4.  when running the npm ci --omit=dev command it modifies the package-lock which I don't need. The idea is to have a package-lock under git, and two commands to execute on the server and the developers (npm ci for dev and npm ci --omit=dev for prod).  does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 79):

#### Override `NODE_ENV` variable

When your `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to **production**, using `npm ci` will not install devDependencies. But if you still want to install **devDependencies**

```
npm ci --include=dev
```

will do the trick ;)

---

##### For versions older than NPM v7.x, use

```
npm ci --also=dev
```

Comment: As v7 the `also` option is deprecated. Use `--include=dev` instead. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#also