# Should I copy `package-lock.json` to the container image in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, package.json, docker-build

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12-slim

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /

# COPY . . # COPY ENTIRE FOLDER ?

COPY ./package.json ./package.json
COPY ./dist ./dist

RUN npm install --only=production

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT npm start
```

Here is my `.dockerignore` file:

```
node_modules
```

You see that I'm just copying `package.json` and not `package-lock.json`. I guessed that, since I'll be running `RUN npm install` to build the image, I thought that it should create its own `package-lock.json`.

But I got this warning during the build:

```
> Step #0: > protobufjs@6.10.2 postinstall /node_modules/protobufjs
> Step #0: > node scripts/postinstall
> Step #0:
> Step #0: npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
> Step #0: npm WARN knative-serving-helloworld@1.0.0 No repository field.    
> Step #0: 
> Step #0: added 304 packages from 217 contributors and audited 312 packages in 15.27s
```

So, should I add this to my `Dockerfile`?

```
COPY ./package-lock.json ./package-lock.json
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should absolutely copy the `package-lock.json` file in.  It has a slightly different role from the `package.json` file: `package.json` can declare "I'm pretty sure my application works with version 17 of the `react` package", where `package-lock.json` says "I have built and tested with exactly version 17.0.1 of that package".

Once you have both files, there is a separate [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci) command that's optimized for this case.

```sh
COPY package.json package-lock.json .
# Run `npm ci` _before_ copying the application in
RUN NODE_ENV=production npm ci
# If any file in `dist` changes, this will stop Docker layer caching
COPY ./dist ./dist
```

Comment: Thanks, I've also found more information on `npm ci` and its behavior with `devDependencies` on this other question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065865/is-there-a-way-of-making-npm-ci-install-devdependencies-or-npm-install-not

Answer (score 5):

It depends if you want to have exactly the same env everywhere.
If yes, package-lock.json is needed. There is a nice post about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64014814/4925213

Comment: I guess that since I'm installing `--only production`, the `package-lock.json` will be different than the one I have in my local dev environment, right? 'Cause there are some `devDependencies` in `package.json`. Should I leave it out and ignore the warning, then?

Comment: You should have "dev" flag for devDependencies in package-lock.json, so it should remain the same. When you are building for production devDependencies should be excluded using that flag.