# What is the NPM equivalent of "yarn install --frozen-lockfile"?

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, package-lock.json

I'm using `npm` as part of me building the production docker image.
I want to make sure the `package-lock.json` doesn't change and matches.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use `npm ci`.

> npm ci bypasses a package’s package.json to install modules from a package’s lockfile. This ensures reproducible builds—you are getting exactly what you expect on every install.

https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171556855892/introducing-npm-ci-for-faster-more-reliable

Comment: That doesn't ensure that it matches the `package.json` though?

Comment: @VoxPelli the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci) state that "if dependencies in the package lock do not match those in package.json, `npm ci` will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock."

Comment: sadly `npm ci` will delete node_modules, so it has a quite annoying penalty for ci pipelines by removing the cache.

Comment: @Salz maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60355056/3016654

Comment: @AndreiTătar thanks, should at least prevent the redownload.