# Github action npm cache minimal example doesn’t work

Tags: node.js, caching, github-actions

I have a minimal example of a Github action workflow that implements an npm module cache. I want to speed up npm install by using locally cached modules instead of downloading them each time.

Here’s the workflow:

```
name: Build
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main
      - fix-*
      - feature-*
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  nodejs_version: ${{ github.event.inputs.nodejs_version || '20.4.0' }}
  repo_dir: repo
  cache_name: npm-modules-cache 
 
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Clone Deploy Repository (Latest)
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.repo_dir }}
 
      - name: Setup NodeJS
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.nodejs_version }}

      - name: List node modules (1)
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list

      - name: Restore npm module cache
        uses: actions/cache/restore@v3
        id: cache-npm-restore
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache_name }}
          
      - name: List node modules (2)
        if: ${{ steps.cache-npm-restore.outputs.cache-hit == 'true' }}
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list

      - name: Install NodeJS modules
        run: | 
          cd $repo_dir && npm install
 
      - name: Save npm module cache
        if: ${{ steps.cache-npm-restore.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
        uses: actions/cache/save@v3
        id: cache-npm-save
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache_name }}

      - name: List node modules (3)
        if: ${{ steps.cache-npm-restore.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list
 
      - name: Build
        run: |
          cd $repo_dir && npm run build
          
      - name: Test
        run: |
          cd $repo_dir && npm run test
      
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
  
    steps:
      - name: Clone Deploy Repository (Latest)
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.repo_dir }}

      - name: List node modules (4)
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list
          
      - name: Restore npm module cache
        uses: actions/cache/restore@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache_name }}
 
      - name: List node modules (5)
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list

      - name: Install NodeJS modules
        run: | 
          cd $repo_dir && npm install
          
      - name: Build
        run: |
          cd $repo_dir && npm run deploy
```

When run the build job successfully creates a cache, and the deploy job successfully restores the cache, however the deploy job “List node modules (5)” step shows that none of the modules are present, and so the npm install command doesn’t install using the cache.

Why isn’t the cache working? How can I fix the workflow so the cache is used to install the modules quickly?

Update: I tried moving the cache to .npm as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60355056/9953198). Same result. The cache still isn’t being used:

List node modules (5) output:

```
Run cd $repo_dir && npm list
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! missing: chai@^4.3.6, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: chance@^1.1.8, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: cheerio@^1.0.0-rc.12, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: debug@^4.2.0, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: ejs@^3.1.6, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: highlight.js@^11.7.0, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: marked@^4.2.4, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: mocha@^10.0.0, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: sinon@^14.0.0, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1 /home/runner/work/workflow-npm-dependency-cache/workflow-npm-dependency-cache/repo
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY chai@^4.3.6
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY chance@^1.1.8
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY cheerio@^1.0.0-rc.12
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY debug@^4.2.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY ejs@^3.1.6
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY highlight.js@^11.7.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY marked@^4.2.4
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY mocha@^10.0.0
└── UNMET DEPENDENCY sinon@^14.0.0
```

Even though the restore from deploy job worked:

Output from deploy job “Restore npm module cache” step:

```
Run actions/cache/restore@v3
Received 195 of 195 (100.0%), 0.0 MBs/sec
Cache Size: ~0 MB (195 B)
/usr/bin/tar -xf /home/runner/work/_temp/b7061dc5-d9d8-46a8-84c4-8ac40b635d39/cache.tzst -P -C /home/runner/work/workflow-npm-dependency-cache/workflow-npm-dependency-cache --use-compress-program unzstd
Cache restored successfully
Cache restored from key: Linux-build-npm-modules-cache
```

Update: The other files from minimal example:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "workflow-npm-dependency-cache",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Minimal example of a workflow npm cache",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "echo Building...",
    "test": "echo Testing...",
    "deploy": "echo Deploying..."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "debug": "^4.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "marked": "^4.2.4",
    "highlight.js": "^11.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "chance": "^1.1.8",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "sinon": "^14.0.0"
  }
}
```

That’s all you need to reproduce the issue.

Comment: There was previously an attempted answer and a discussion which suddenly got deleted before I was able to answer. The minimal example repo isn’t public though I can provide all files via copy paste if necessary. It’s very minimal.

Comment: I added the package.json file so you have all necessary files to create the minimal example.